# Advertising on other SE sites: 2019 Version

Tags: discussion, advertising

It is open season for posting ads on other sites. It might be a good idea to take advantage of this to help 3dPrinting.SE grow. I'm wondering what everyone might think about it?

If it does interest you, please post up an answer to this question with where you might think would be a good place to advertise. Usually, the other site would need to relate to this one in some way. It's been my experience if it doesn't relate, the ad will get shut (or shot) down.

If you feel you have the artistry to create an ad for another site, post that up, too! We can critique the work and ensure most everyone likes the idea before posting it over. We really do want to put our best foot forward! There are some rules in making an image:

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

If you have some ideas and would like to discuss, you can also post ideas or questions a little more free form over on the [site chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79830/public-3d-printing-room).

If you like the idea, please let everyone know!

Answer (score 3):

Considering 3D printing needs 3D models, I think it would be natural to advertise on [Blender.SE](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2580/13218), perhaps with a catchphrase like "Want to print your Blender model?"

[GraphicDesign.SE](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3573/30985) also has questions about 3D design (not necessarily 3D *model*), and the scope on 3D-related questions is debatable. Regardless of that, I think there's nothing to lose trying to advertise there?

Comment: I think this is definitely doable and is absolutely related in both cases. We'd need some ideas as to what we can do as far as the images behind the ads. I like the idea of the Blender quote ... I think it's a starting point and something we can work with.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)? 3D printers are pieces of engineering ingenuity, we sometimes receive questions that should be asked at the Engineering stack, I could imagine that there is a need for the other way around where people are interested in materializing their engineering question or solution.

As I'm seriously lacking graphical design skills; I cannot really contribute to the actual design, but what may be interesting is to have a printed gear/sprocket morph into an actual gear/sprocket with the text "How about materialize your idea" or something with similar context.

This could be something to start from:
[image: sprocket or gear example]

Comment: Makes some sense! What are you thinking for the ad itself? Any ideas?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Updated the answer to include an idea for the banner.

Comment: In the same vein, Electronics.SE is pretty much out sister side when it comes to wiring.

Comment: @0scar - Anyway to fit something like that into a 600x500 pixel image? The ad could read something like: *Imagine. Design. Slice.* along the top, then *3DPrinting.SE* along the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a great idea.  StackOverflow is by for the most populated site (and the one I came from).

3D printing interests nerdy-trendy folks like those the in SO, that's where I can from.

Prehaps woodworking SE sites would work as well.

Comment: We can try this. However, when you advertise something which really is unrelated, the reality of it getting sponsored (getting six votes) becomes pretty slim.

Comment: Woodworking would have a large crossover.  Engineering too and maybe boardgame people.