# Migrating questions to grow this site into a bigger and more active community?

Tags: discussion

I'm dissapointed in the size of the active community on this site, considering how long the site has been active (https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82438/3d-printing) and how mainstream 3D printing is. It's visible on the amount of views and votes that questions get, and the lack of answers on many questions. As well as a handful of users that are usually involved. It's unfortunate, I for example really like the (also relatively small) Information Security Stack site which is much more active.

I thought of ways to get people to even know about the existance of this site:

- Posting links to this site on other sites such as when posting a make, or object on Thingiverse and Printables
- Using it more commonly in YouTube comments or other comments to link to answers or questions that are applicable in the context
- Question Migration from more popular sites such as StackOverflow, below are some examples of search queries that result in many (not all) questions that belong to this site instead:

  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=3d+printing
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=3d+print
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stl+obj
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ender+3
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=klipper
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gcode
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=creality
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=octoprint
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prusa
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cura+slicer
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=marlin
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bed+leveling
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pla+filament
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=print+filament
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thingiverse
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=grabcad

I think migration (also from other sites) is perhaps the most effective for multiple reasons. As I believe the user is notified, also more relevant content is available on this site making it easier found when using search engines. What are your thoughts on this, why isn't this community bigger and more active, did it used to be, what was already tried?

*Also, not enough up and downvoting decreases the quality of this site a lot, since it's much harder to distinguish good quality from lower quality content.*

Comment: I've just remembered that we have a [Public 3D Printing chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79830/public-3d-printing-room). It might be worth popping in there to discuss some of your meta points with some other members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Similar concerns about the size of the community have been raised for many years, as the links below show.

---

#### Migration

##### General

It is worth remembering that *migration* only has a rather small window (of a few days or so) after which a question is deemed "too old to migrate" and the option just greyed out (or unavailable, I forget which now)... annoying I know, but those are the rules.

IMHO, migration is pointless (and can require "back-channel" communication and agreements between sites) and just not worth the bother. Generally, it is much more simpler and efficient (and rapid) to just ask the poster to delete their question on the first site and just re-post it themselves on the new site.

A *very* similar question was asked recently on the Robotics Meta, please read [Can/should questions on Stack Overflow about ROS be migrated here?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/9176). The [answer](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1476/9176) seems to also apply to this site and (more or less) re-iterates what I said above.

Also, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137931/280335) to [Is "Too old to migrate" a good reason NOT to migrate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136537/280335) is really useful.

##### Other sites

I looked at some of the [G-code questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gcode) and a number of them are related to simply programmatic issues, parsing issues or substitution, that don't have a 3D Printing end-game, and so they wouldn't be on-topic anyway.

The [Robotics site](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) was in a real lull until quite recently, when the [ROS (Q&A) community was merged](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501/9176). In the past some 3D printing questions *were* posted there, and I *did* think about getting those migrated, but then the OP had a meltdown and rage-quit, so that was the end of that.

The [Engineering site](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) also has some 3D design/modelling questions that *could* have fitted here, but (as has been [stated elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80216/can-i-ask-the-same-question-on-more-than-one-stack-exchange-site#:%7E:text=Ask%20on%20the%20site%20you,is%20a%20very%20bad%20idea.)) it is OK for some overlap to exist between SE sites, a question might be suited to *more than one site* and it doesn't really matter where it lands - the question just gets slightly re-jigged for the appropriate audience.

#### Traffic

There are graphs and spreadsheets and databases that can be queried to give you this sort of info. Early numbers can be seen in [this (now rather ramshackle) answer](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/265/4762) to [What does it take to get out of Beta stage?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/264/4762).

Also (vaguely) related are questions discussing participation:

- [New users aren't posting their own questions - are we scaring them off?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/511/4762)
- more to be added as they are found...

##### A subjective view

I have had the (possibly unjustified) *feeling* that the site has tailed off since early 2022 or so (as I noted at the end of [this answer](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/557/4762) to [Is 3dprinting.stackexchange.com likely to still be active in the foreseeable future?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/556/4762)).

My *overall impression* is that this site was vibrant and had at least 10+ permanently active users, seven years ago, back in 2016. The questions back then seemed to be more related to:

- building DIY printers;
- fixing Prusa printers and their clones;
- filament queries;
- general Arduino questions, and;
- firmware issues.

However, 3D printing has become much more mainstream, in the past few years, there are many more reliable manufacturers of printers that (apparently) just "work out of the box" and less people are building from scratch. So, less questions... apart from the initial flurry of Creality support questions<sup>1</sup>, when these printers first started to become popular (4-5 years ago?).

Nevertheless, even these types of questions seem to have tailed off, now, after a *subsequent* flurry of questions about Creality add-ons, such as the BLTouch (et al).

Also, w.r.t. repair, as 0scar states, most of the tinkering and repairing questions have already been asked and answered, back in the days of DIY printers. However, now and again a good old-fashioned board repair question comes along that you can get your teeth into, but they are becoming increasingly infrequent.

Nowadays, we *seem* to be down to a core of 4 or 5 regular visitors and  a few other less-regular users.

###### Chat room

I've just remembered that we also have a vibrant chat room (*two* in fact, see [Do we have a chatroom?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/307/4762)), which were active in 2018 onwards, and (after having just checked) the [Public 3D Printing chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79830/public-3d-printing-room) still is.

#### Promotion

There was the opportunity to advertise our site, using community ads, but I'm not sure what ever came of that.

See:

- [Community Ads! Let's make 2d ads for ourselves!](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/community-ads-lets-make-2d-ads-for-ourselves)
- [Which SE sites should we target with community ads?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/which-se-sites-should-we-target-with-community-ads)
- [Advertising on other SE sites: 2019 Version](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/384/4762)

Also, this question has (sort of) been asked before, [How do we get more traffic to the site?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/74/4762)

#### Voting

You *do* raise a good point: No votes makes it hard to *sort the wheat from the chaff*.

Again, the voting (or apparent lack thereof) has been raised in the past, see:

- [How do we motivate users to vote and advertise the voting policy?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/how-do-we-motivate-users-to-vote-and-advertise-the-voting-policy)
- [Vote early, Vote often](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/vote-early-vote-often)
- [Remember to vote!](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196/remember-to-vote)

Although, all of these seem to be from 2016. I really thought that there were a couple more recently asked questions... but maybe there aren't.

---

##### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> See the tail end of [this answer](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/328/4762) and [this comment](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264/what-does-it-take-to-get-out-of-beta-stage/265#comment802_328)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there are more volatile other media then there used to be, e.g. Reddit, but the quality of the answers there is generally disappointing. There is so much more information, video channels and fora to be found that each has their own dedicated group of users.

SE tries to aim for high quality (community) moderator driven question and answer sites, this just doesn't addresses everybody, sometimes people want to go into endless discussions for which SE is not the platform.

The analytics page ([visible for 5000 rep users](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), but a history is maintained fro a while in [What does it take to get out of Beta stage?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/265/)) shows that the site gets frequently hit, many first timers that are drawn here through search engine queries.

Do note that 3D printing is in effect a pretty simple process, like an internal combustion engine needs air, fuel and a spark, a 3D printer needs a location, filament heating and preprocessed file; after a while most questions are asked. Appearently, the users find their answers in the existing questions. New techniques and advances in firmware and software trigger new questions like recently we receive more Klipper, input shaping and Resin related print questions.

Migration "from and to" other sites does happen but not frequent. The provided links do show many topics related to 3D printing, but looking at the questions, the vast majority does not belong here according to our [*"What topics can I ask about here?"*](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I personally disagree to the 'after a while most questions are asked', out of a personal urge to keep innovating. But you're probably right for the average user. However, it doesn't address my specific question about the strategy of migrating content from other sites. What's your view on that?

Comment: Considering the overwhelming flood of cheap 3D printers in the market and the inexperienced user base the most questions are asked already, many new ones are related or in the troubleshooting category. Hence my referring to the new software/firmware options that may spark new questions. Migration is not necessary for most of the questions in the link (caveat, I haven't looked at all the links you provided). But if a question might be better suitable here you could raise the migration flag on any question you encounter, moderators will view your request and decide if migration is justified.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the Quintarchy of users that managed to get more than 10000 Rep here, and someone that was very active like 2 years ago I can tell you a tale that might exemplarify why migration *can* help, but doesn't happen a lot:

### A tale of 3 Printers

My tale of 3D printing began with a silly question about [perfect 3D printed dice.](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4849/how-do-i-3d-print-fair-dice) Which, actually **didn't** star here: it was migrated from RPG.SE over here. It made me aware of the place. I made that question back then way before I had my own printer, but after a couple of material science classes that discussed pretty much the contents of the answer to the question and I tried to apply it to a hobby. It brought me to another hobby I would soon pick up: About christmas I bought my first printer, a TronXY X1. It was cheap, it was a tinker machine with a crazy wobbly gantry out of the box and I re-engineered [a gantry slider](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2275654) for it that turned out to act like a spring on itself and keep the gantry with a little load and thus straight. It was a project in itself. In July 2018 I finally took my step to buy an Ender 3. The version 1, but not the very first production run. I started to look up trying to get an inductive probe running, so I figured out [voltage first](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6342/what-voltage-does-the-creality-ender-3-run-at), [then a setup](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6358/inductive-sensor-in-24-v-machine), and came to a hiccup: I needed to update Firmware.

That firmware update sent me down the drain: I had never worked with firmware before, and half the answers were very cryptic to me as a beginner. But I sat down with Greenonline in chat and we went on a deep dive into what actually was the board in the machine I bought, and how to actually install firmware on it. It was a crazy few days for me, and I learned more between the bouts of feeling overwhelmed and seeing some success and waiting for an arduino to actually flash the firmware! It led to a flurry of questions: starting by [recalibrating](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/recalibrating-home-position), trying to [install hex firmware](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6654/how-to-install-a-hex-firmware), [making my own hex file](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/export-firmware-as-a-hex) for a modified firmware, and [flashing the board](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6685/how-to-install-new-atmega-firmware-via-the-isp-pins) before going full circle. Many of these questions would not be amiss on Adruino or Stack Overflow, but their context was always dealing with my printer.

The Ender3 had just about as hefty a learning curve as dealing with the mechanical wobble of the TronXY X1 at first. But I had this community (and chat) as my support. Why was the learnign curve so hefty? Well, the initial V1 was not good. It was cheap, it had problems. [Like the Z-endstop is from the factory misaligned,](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6807/sudden-underextrusion-on-ender3) I ruinied [about 5 or such glue on surfaces](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7960/how-to-clean-up-my-build-plate-for-a-new-build-surface), [Thermal Runaway PRotection wasn't flashed by default](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8466/what-is-thermal-runaway-protection), the extriuder lever breaking could not be seen easily, leading me down to esoteric questions that to me now read like ["Why the F... is my Layer height wrong?"](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10986/how-to-calculate-the-proper-layer-height-multiples) and only some week after I noticed the break and got an aluminium replacement, firmware needed another upgrade to turn on [Power Loss recovery after the TRP upgrade did lack it](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10571/how-to-activate-power-loss-recovery-in-marlin) (though it never saw use - crazy stable power net here)...  I even started the [Knowledgebase tag](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledgebase) to make some of the most common-appearing questions easily findable. A Hotend swap required [a PID Tune](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/18720/how-to-properly-run-a-pid-tuning-and-update-the-firmware) (which I only documented about a year later!)...

And then my Ender3 v1 broke as I moved it. The extruder stepper driver just fizzled. So I bought an Ender3 V2, put it together but out of the box swapped the extruder for the aluminium one, and... I kind of realized that I had no more questions that I either hadn't learned or asked about previously and that the Ender3 V2 was out of the box and much more user-friendly. It just... **worked**. Sure, it does not come with mesh bed leveling, its firmware isn't perfect, but it just worked.

3D printing had changed **so much** over the years since I started as a 3rd generation hobbyist (as in: 1st Gen was Reprap, 2nd gen was parts kits, 3rd gen is early (ca pre-2019) printers and now... we are way deep in Gen 4 or 5 printers that actively build on the problems of their predecessors. The tech is much more mature, and I am much more knowledgeable.

### migration issue

Now, my tale began with **one** migration. But that is an exception. We got a couple questions that were really ill fits. I helped to establish the benchmark test: "Does the question claim that it's for 3D printing?". But often the questions have no clear target.

There's Blender, but most often that didn't fit. There's engineering, but often the question was not about either. In fact, most questions did not fit **any** stack we knew about.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I appreciate it. I have a software background, less so hardware. It is one of the reasons why I got into 3D printing. I started with a Ender 3 V2, I realize it has evolved a lot already but both cheaper or much better printers are available, I can buy a expensive machine but I rather buy a cheaper model and learn to upgrade it and understand the fundamentals of it. The knowledge gained from that is much more valuable to me than the actual printer is. I still think even with the currently best printers we can still find many things to improve and so, knowledge to share.